# Savitzky-Golay Filter to smooth noisy data

Tags: filtering, signal-processing

I do have noisy data and want to smooth them by a Savitzky-Golay filter because I want to keep the magnitude of the signal.

a) Is there a ready-to-use Filter available for that?

b) what are appropriate values for m (the half width) and for the coefficients for 3000-4000 data points?

Comment: There is one here http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/789/

Comment: Smoothing data depends on lots of things - for example if you are recording the data in `cm^-1`, but you actually need the spectrum in `nm`. Describe the specific applications and also the sampling rate as there are parameters that depend on it. Also have you considered using other tools to smooth your data ?

Comment: @Nasser: found that link, but the m-file can not be downloaded.

Comment: @Nikola Dimitrov: tried a lot of things already (Interpolation,Spline,LSF,Chebyshev); but I need to get the derivative without oscillation and noise. Because of that I like to try smoothing the data by that filter first. Link for example data is provided in the question.

Comment: What is the field of research of that project ? Chemistry ?

Comment: @Nikola: chemistry,thermodynamics.

Comment: I had no problems downloading. Just right-mouse the download icon and choose save as...

Comment: Ahaa, thermodynamics... Interesting :)

Comment: `the m-file can not be downloaded` It worked for me, just downloaded it the m file and the .nb file. The trick is to right-click->Save Link As... and not to click on it.

Comment: Do you have a picture of that derivative ? I obtained a relatively good looking first and second derivatives, but I don't know if I am loosing too much of the energy ..

Comment: Here is a link to some code posted on mathgroup that I have used before and found ok: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2012/Feb/msg00036.html

Comment: For the answer to (b) you need to understand how the filter works and know a bit about your data

Comment: [It seems this functionality is coming.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SavitzkyGolayMatrix.html)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The following code will filter noisy data…

```
SGKernel[left_?NonNegative, right_?NonNegative, degree_?NonNegative, derivative_? NonNegative] :=
Module[{i, j, k, l, matrix, vector},
    matrix = Table[  (* matrix is symmetric *)
        l = i + j;
        If[l == 0,
            left + right + 1,
        (*Else*)
            Sum[k^l, {k, -left, right}]
        ],
        {i, 0, degree},
        {j, 0, degree}
    ];
    vector = LinearSolve[
        matrix, 
        MapAt[1&, Table[0, {degree+1}], derivative+1]
    ];
    (* vector = Inverse[matrix][[derivative + 1]]; *)
    Table[
        vector.Table[If[i == 0, 1, k^i], {i, 0, degree}],
        {k, -left, right}
    ]
] /; derivative <= degree <= left+right


SGSmooth[list_?VectorQ, window_, degree_, derivative_:0]:=
    Module[{pairs},
        pairs = MapThread[List, {Range[Length[list]], list}];
        Map[Last, SGSmooth[pairs, window, degree, derivative]]
    ] 


SGSmooth[list_?MatrixQ, window_, degree_, derivative_:0]:=
    Module[{kernel, list1, list2, margin, space, smoothData},

        (* determine a symmetric margin at the ends of the raw dataset.
        The window width is split in half to make a symmetric window 
        around a data point of interest *)
        margin = Floor[window/2];

        (* take only the 1st column of data in the list to be smoothed (the
        independant Values) and extract the data from the list by removing
        half the window width 'i.e., margin' from the ends of the list *)
        list1 = Take[Map[First, list], {margin + 1, Length[list] - margin}];

        (* take only the 2nd column of data in the list to be smoothed 
        (the dependent Values) and Map them into list2 *)
        list2 = Map[Last, list];

        (* get the kernel coefficients for the left and right margins, the 
           degree, and the requested derivative *)
        kernel = SGKernel[margin, margin, degree, derivative];

        (* correlation of the kernel with the list of dependent values *)
        list2 = ListCorrelate[kernel, list2];

        (* Data _should_ be equally spaced, but... calculate spacing anyway by getting
           the minimum of all the differences in the truncated list1, remove the first 
           and last points of list1 *)
        space = Min[Drop[list1, 1] - Drop[list1, -1]];

        (* condition the dependant values based on spacing and the derivative *)
        list2 = list2*(derivative!/space^derivative);

        (* recombine the correlated (x-y) data pairs (that is list1 and list2), 
        put these values back together again to form the smooth data list *)
        smoothData=Transpose[{list1, list2}]


    ] /; derivative <= degree <= 2*Floor[window/2] && $VersionNumber >= 4.0
```

I did not apply this to your data, but you can do that later.  This example is applied to noisy random data.

Using a noisy sine data function…

```
dataFunction[x_] := Sin[x] + Random[Real, {-π, π}];
```

Build a table of noisy tabular data from $0$ to $2\pi$…

```
dataTable = Table[{x, dataFunction[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, .01}];
```

Animate the smoothing operations.  Notice the smoothed dataset shrinks with increasing 'window width'.  This is an artifact of the `ListCorrelate` function used in the `SGSmooth` function.  `ListCorrelate` uses an end buffered dataset.

NOTE:  The red line is the filtered data set…

```
 Manipulate[
 If[showRawData,
  Show[
   ListPlot[dataTable, PlotRange -> {{0, 2 π}, {-5.0, 5.0}}],
   ListPlot[
    {
     SGSmooth[dataTable, win, order]
     },
    PlotRange -> {{0, 2 π}, {-5.0, 5.0}},
    PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick}, {Green, Thick}},
    Joined -> True]
   ], (* ELSE just plot smooth data *)
  ListPlot[
   {
    SGSmooth[dataTable, win, order]
    },
   PlotRange -> {{0, 2 π}, {-5.0, 5.0}},
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick}, {Green, Thick}},
   Joined -> True]
  ],

 {{win, 100, "window width"}, 2, 300, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{order, 1, "order of polynomial"}, 1, 9, 
  1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{showRawData, True, "Raw Data"}, {True, False}},
 SaveDefinitions -> True
 ]
```

This will create a `Manipulate` similar to the following:

[image: demo]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great!. Thanks for sharing the filter. The last Definition of SGSmooth has a ; too much preventing any output.

Comment: @MarkusRoellig thank you finding this little typo.  I fixed the above code to plot the smoothed data.  I had originally used SGSmooth[] with additional embedded code and did not remove the ';'.  My apologies...

Comment: @Joseph: Thank you, that answer is great! Just a question: It is described in literature that the calculation of the derivatives can be directly implemented in the SG-filter (see: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ac50031a048). I guess this would be an expansion of your solution, right? If so, I open another question and let you know?

Comment: @Shukoff:  You can use the existing code as is to calculate the data derivative.  That is the beauty of the SG filter.  This implementation is very similar to the Numerical Recipes implemetation (http://www.wire.tu-bs.de/OLDWEB/mameyer/cmr/savgol.pdf).  Just use: SGSmooth[dataTable, win, order, 1] for 1st derivative, SGSmooth[dataTable, win, order, 2] for 2nd derivative, etc...

Comment: @Joseph: your implementation is superb! Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I'm just posting this to record for posterity [something I posted in the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4829800#4829800) a not-so-long time ago. As I noted there, the following routine will only do smoothing; <del>I had a more general routine for generating the differentiation coefficients, but I still have not been able to find it</del>. (For the more general, but less compact version, see below.) As with Virgil's method (the one in Alexey's answer), this is based on [Gorry's procedure](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ac00205a007) (though I have traced the spirit of the algorithm going as far back as [Hildebrand's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=hqucruPBheQC&pg=PA357)):

```
GramP[k_Integer, m_Integer, t_Integer] :=
     (-1)^k HypergeometricPFQ[{-k, k + 1, -t - m}, {1, -2 m}, 1]

SavitzkyGolay[n_Integer, m_Integer, t_Integer] := 
        Table[Sum[(Binomial[2 m, k]/Binomial[2 m + k + 1, k + 1])
                  GramP[k, m, i] GramP[k, m, t] (1 + k/(k + 1)), {k, 0, n}, 
                  Method -> "Procedural"], {i, -m, m}]
SavitzkyGolay[n_Integer, m_Integer] := Table[SavitzkyGolay[n, m, t], {t, -m, m}]
```

Usage is pretty straightforward: `n` is the order of the polynomial smoothing; `2 m + 1` is the window size, and `t` tells how much to shift the window.

---

**Added 12/17/2015**

Here is a faster routine for evaluating the Gram polynomial, using some undocumented functionality:

```
GramP[k_Integer, m_Integer, t_Integer] :=
      (-1)^k Internal`DCHypergeometricPFQ[k, {-k, k + 1, -m - t}, {1, -2 m}, 1]
```

---

I managed to finally recover the general SG routine I once wrote through the kind assistance of a friend. To share my joy, I now release this to you:

```
Options[SavitzkyGolay] = {Derivative -> 0, WorkingPrecision -> Infinity};

SavitzkyGolay[n_Integer?Positive, m_Integer?Positive, t_Integer,
              OptionsPattern[]] /; 1 < n < 2 m + 1 && -m <= t <= m := 
Module[{o = OptionValue[Derivative], c, s, h, p, q, u, v, w},
       u = UnitVector[o + 1, 1]; v = ConstantArray[0, o + 1]; 
       c = 1/(2 m + 1); s = Join[{Boole[o == 0] c},
       Table[h = 0;
             {p, q} = {2 (2 k - 1), (k - 1) (2 m + k)}/(k (2 m - k + 1));
             Do[w = u[[j]]; (* evaluate Gram polynomial and derivatives *)
                u[[j]] = p (t w + (j - 1) h) - q v[[j]];
                v[[j]] = h = w,
                {j, Min[k, o] + 1}];
             c *= (2 m - k + 1) (1 + 1/k)/(2 m + k + 1);
             c (1 + k/(k + 1)) u[[o + 1]],
             {k, n}]];
       Table[h = s[[n]] + 2 (2 n - 1) (p = s[[n + 1]]) j/(n (2 m - n + 1));
             Do[q = p; p = h; (* Clenshaw's recurrence *)
                h = s[[k]] + 2 (2 k - 1) p j/(k (2 m - k + 1)) -
                    k (2 m + k + 1) q/((k + 1) (2 m - k)),
                {k, n - 1, 1, -1}];
                N[h, OptionValue[WorkingPrecision]], {j, -m, m}] // 
    Developer`ToPackedArray];

SavitzkyGolay[n_Integer?Positive, m_Integer?Positive, opts___?OptionQ] /; 
  1 < n < 2 m + 1 := 
 Developer`ToPackedArray[Table[SavitzkyGolay[n, m, t, opts], {t, -m, m}]]
```

As advertised, it uses no matrices, and instead uses the recurrence relation of the Gram polynomial. If need be, the guts of the routine can be embedded within a `Compile[]`.

---

**Added 12/17/2015**

Altho `SavitzkyGolayMatrix[]` is now built-in in version 10, it is only limited to producing the "central" coefficients, as opposed to the routine `SavitzkyGolay[]` in this answer that can also generate coefficients for the left and right ends.

```
SavitzkyGolayMatrix[{2}, 3, 1, WorkingPrecision -> ∞]
   {1/12, -2/3, 0, 2/3, -1/12}

SavitzkyGolay[3, 2, 0 (* central *), Derivative -> 1]
   {1/12, -2/3, 0, 2/3, -1/12}
```

In general, the result of `SavitzkyGolayMatrix[]` is built from appropriate outer products of coefficient lists.

```
SavitzkyGolayMatrix[{3, 4}, {2, 3}, WorkingPrecision -> ∞] ===
Outer[Times, SavitzkyGolay[2, 3, 0], SavitzkyGolay[3, 4, 0]]
   True
```

Comment: Please add an example how it should be applied to a data (as an interesting data I suggest [IR spectrum of gaseous water](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7732185&Units=SI&Type=IR-SPEC&Index=0#IR-SPEC)). What is  the meaning of the coefficients which `SavitzkyGolay` returns?

Comment: @Alexey, I'll add a usage example later. For now: `SavitzkyGolay[n, m, Derivative -> d]` corresponds to `LSCoeffs[m, n, d]` in Virgil's implementation in your answer.

Answer (score 11):

Several years ago in [related MathGroups thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/5k6rHhIfUXY/62WGusZFAiMJ) Virgil P. Stokes suggested:

> A few years back I wrote a *Mathematica* notebook that shows how one can
>   obtain the SG smoother from Gram polynomials. The code is not very
>   elegant; but, it is a rather general implementation that should be
>   easy to understand. Contact me if you are interested and I will be
>   glad to forward the notebook to you.

I contacted him and received the notebook. I find his implementation of the Savitzky-Golay filter quite stable and working pretty well. Here I publish it with his permission:

```
Clear[m, i]; (* m, i are global variables !! *)
Clear[GramPolys, LSCoeffs, SGSmooth];

GramPolys[mm_, nmax_] := 
  Module[{k, m = mm},  (* equations (1a), (1b) *)
      (* Define recursive equation for Gram polynomials as a function of m,i for degrees 0,1,...,nmax *)
      p[m, 0, i] = 1; 
      p[m, -1, i] = 0;    
      p[m_, k_, i_] := 
    p[m, k, i] = 2*(2*k - 1)/(k*(2*m - k + 1))*i*p[m, k - 1, i] - 
                                         (k - 
         1)*(2*m + k)/(k*(2*m - k + 1))*p[m, k - 2, i];

      (* Return coefficients for degrees 0,1,...,nmax in a list *) 
      Table[p[mm, k, i] // FullSimplify, {k, 0, nmax}]    
   ]; 

LSCoeffs[m_, n_, d_] := 
  Module[{k, j, sum, clist, polynomial, cclist},   
   polynomial = GramPolys[m, n];
   clist = {};
   Do[(* points in each sliding window *)
    sum = 0;
    Do[ (* degree loop *)
         num = (2 k + 1) FactorialPower[2 m, k];
         den = FactorialPower[2 m + k + 1, k + 1];
         t1 = polynomial[[k + 1]] /. {i -> j};
         t2 = polynomial[[k + 1]]; 
         sum = sum + (num/den)*t1*t2 // FullSimplify;
         (*Print["k,polynomial[[k+1]]: ",k,", ",polynomial[[k+1]]];*)
     , {k, 0, n}];
       clist = Append[clist, sum];
    , {j, -m, m}];
   Table[D[clist, {i, d}] /. {i -> j}, {j, -m, m}]
   ];

SGSmooth[cc_, data_] := Module[{m, y, datal, datar, k, kk, n, yy},

   n = Length[data];
   m = (Length[cc] - 1)/2;

   (* Left end  --- first 2*m+1 points used *)
   datal = Take[data, 2*m + 1];
   (* Smooth first m points (1,2,...,m-1,m) *)
   kk = 0;
   Table[(kk = kk + 1; 
     y[k] = ListConvolve[Reverse[cc[[kk]]], datal][[1]]), {k, -m, -1}];

   (* Smooth central points (m+1,m+2,...n-m-1) *)
   y[0] = ListConvolve[Reverse[cc[[m + 1]]], data];

   (* Right end --- last 2*m+1 points used *)
   datar = Take[data, {n - (2*m + 1) + 1, n}];
   (* Smooth last m points (n-m,n-m+1,...,n) *)
   kk = m + 1;
   Table[(kk = kk + 1; 
     y[k] = ListConvolve[Reverse[cc[[kk]]], datar][[1]]), {k, 1, m}];

   (* And now we concatenate the front-end, central, and back-
   end estimated data values *)
   yy = Join[Table[y[k], {k, -m, -1}], y[0], Table[y[k], {k, 1, m}]]
   ];
```

> ```
> Usage: SGOutput = SGSmooth[LSCoeffs[m,n,d], data]
> Inputs: 
>    m   =  half-width of smoothing window; i.e., 2m+1 points in smoothing kernel
>    n   =  degree of LS polynomial (n < 2m+1)
>    d   =  order of derivative (d =0, smoother; d = 1, 1st derivative; ...)
>    data = list of uniformly sampled (spaced) data values to be smoothed (length(data) >=2m+1)  
> Outputs:
>    SGOutput =  list of smoothed data values
> ```

Comment: I really should try looking for that old notebook I wrote for these coefficients; I remember using an algorithm that did not need to generate the Gram polynomials themselves, and worked with the recurrence coefficients.

Comment: @J.M. [Here](http://sharesend.com/b0ynubnp) you can download the original Notebook sent me by Virgil.

Comment: Could you share the file one more time, Alexey? Many thanks.

Comment: @LuciferYellow Take it [here](http://www.solidfiles.com/d/e70a40c1f7/).

Answer (score 5):

I came across the code pasted below a couple of years back and have been using it ever since. It has the advantage that you can apply it also to {x,y} data right away. (BTW, it looks like PH Lundow's code below, last updated back in 2007, is in parts very similar to the one posted by John...)
Best,
Frank
PS
I just noticed, that the built-in SavitzkyGolayMatrix function does not seem to be capable of generating higher order (>2) derivatives. So it makes perfectly sense to use a separate package for the task even if it's slower.

---

```
(* :Title: Smooth *)

(* :Context: "Smooth`" *)

(* :Author:
    P.H. Lundow
    Bug reports to phl@kth.se
*)
(* :Summary:
    Functions for smoothing equidistant data with a Savitsky-Golay filter.
*)
(* :History:
    020507 Created.
    030417 Smooth extended to lists of y-values.
    030425 Added SmoothAll.
    030619 Added MinimumDistance and EquidistantData.
    030923 Small improvement in SGKernel.
    070618 Clean-up.
*)
(* :Mathematica Version: 4.0 *)
(* :Keywords: *) 
(* :Limitations: *) 
(* :Discussion:
    There is room for improvement here. Returned list of smoothed
    data is shorter than original list. Find a better way to
    produce many kernels that takes care of the margins.
*)


BeginPackage["Smooth`"]

SGKernel::usage =
    "SGKernel[left, right, degree, derivative] returns the Savitsky-Golay
    kernel used by the function Smooth when convoluting the data.
    The kernel has length left+right+1. Left is the number of
    leftward data points and right is the number of rightward
    points. Degree refers to the degree of the polynomial and
    derivative is the order of the desired derivative.\nRef:
    Numerical Recipes, chapter 14.8."

Smooth::usage = 
        "Smooth[list, window, degree, derivative] returns the smoothed form
    of equally spaced and sorted data. This is done by fitting polynomials
    of a given degree to a moving window of the list. Argument list is
    either a list of pairs {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...} or a list {y1,y2,...}
    where the x-values are taken to be 1,2,3... If a derivative of the
    data is desired then give the order of the derivative, default is 0.
    \nExample:\n a=Table[{x,Sin[x]+Random[Real,{-1,1}],{x,0,2*Pi,0.001}];
    \n b=Smooth[a,15,2];
    \n c=Smooth[a,15,2,1];
    \n This fits 2:nd degree polynomials to moving windows of width 15 to
    the data. List b is the smoothed data and list c is the derivative of
    the data."

SmoothAll::usage =
    "SmoothAll[{vector,matrix}, window, degree, derivative] works like
    Smooth except that vector is a list of x-values and matrix is a list
    of lists of y-values at the corresponding x-values. The result is
    returned on the same form.\nExample:\n xold={1,2,3,4,5};
    \n yold={{1,3,5,4,4},{2,3,3,2,1},{3,4,6,4,3}};
    \n {xnew,ynew}=SmoothAll[{xold,yold},2,1,0];"

MinimumDistance::usage = 
    "MinimumDistance[data] returns the minimum distance between
    two x-values in the data which is a list of lists. The
    x-values are the first positions of each sublist."

EquidistantData::usage =
    "EquidistantData[data] extracts the largest chunk of
    equidistant data from a list of lists.\nExample:\n
    EquidistantData[{{0,1},{2,8},{3,7},{4,9},{6,3}}] returns the
    list\n {{2,8},{3,7},{4,9}}."

Begin["`Private`"]

definitions = {MinimumDistance, EquidistantData, SGKernel, Smooth, SmoothAll}

Scan[Unprotect, definitions]


MinimumDistance[data:{__List}] :=
    Module[{x},
        x = Map[First, data];
        Min[Drop[x, 1] - Drop[x, -1]]
    ]


EquidistantData[data:{__List}] :=
    Module[{min, len, pos, tmp},
        min = MinimumDistance[data];
        tmp = Split[data, (#1[[1]] + min == #2[[1]])&];
        len = Map[Length, tmp];
        pos = Flatten[Position[len, Max[len], Infinity, 1]][[1]];
        tmp[[pos]]
    ]


SGKernel[left_?NonNegative, right_?NonNegative, degree_?NonNegative, 
    derivative_?NonNegative] :=
    Module[{i, j, k, l, matrix, vector},
        matrix = Table[  (* matrix is symmetric *)
            l = i + j;
            If[l == 0,
                left + right + 1,
            (*Else*)
                Sum[k^l, {k, -left, right}]
            ],
            {i, 0, degree},
            {j, 0, degree}
        ];
        vector = LinearSolve[
            matrix, 
            MapAt[1&, Table[0, {degree+1}], derivative+1]
        ];
        (* vector = Inverse[matrix][[derivative + 1]]; *)
        Table[
            vector.Table[If[i == 0, 1, k^i], {i, 0, degree}],
            {k, -left, right}
        ]
        ] /; derivative <= degree <= left+right


Smooth[list_?MatrixQ, window_, degree_, derivative_:0]:=
    Module[{kernel, list1, list2, margin, space},
        margin = Floor[window/2];
        list1 = Take[
            Map[First, list], 
            {margin + 1, Length[list] - margin}
        ];
        list2 = Map[Last, list];
        kernel = SGKernel[margin, margin, degree, derivative];
        list2 = ListCorrelate[kernel, list2];
        (* Data _should_ be equally spaced, but... *)
        space = Min[Drop[list1, 1] - Drop[list1, -1]];
        list2 = list2*(derivative!/space^derivative);
        Transpose[{list1, list2}]
    ] /; derivative <= degree <= 2*Floor[window/2] && $VersionNumber >= 4.0

Smooth[list_?VectorQ, window_, degree_, derivative_:0]:=
    Module[{pairs},
        pairs = MapThread[List, {Range[Length[list]], list}];
        Map[Last, Smooth[pairs, window, degree, derivative]]
    ]


SmoothAll[{x_?VectorQ, y_?MatrixQ}, window_, degree_, derivative_:0]:=
    Module[{old, new, tmp},
        tmp = Map[(
            old = Transpose[{x, #}];
            new = Smooth[old, window, degree, derivative];
            Map[Last, new])&,
            y
        ];
        {Map[First, new], tmp}
    ]


Scan[Protect, definitions]


End[]

EndPackage[]
```