# Quantum Dot Absorbance Data Peakfinding

Tags: automation, peak-detection

I work in a lab making quantum dots, and was recently tasked with finding a way to extract some figures of merit from old data in an automated way. In particular, I'm looking to extract the peak position, and FWHM from a Gaussian fit of said peak. I believe this would normally be relatively trivial, however the data has an unusual shape, which is not playing nicely with Mathematica's built-in functions. An example of the data, zoomed into the ROI is available [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/9bac221d-9628-4502-ba2d-3c461e933e51)

My current procedure is as follows:

1. Smooth data using Savitsky-Golay (Code obtained from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37380/savitzky-golay-filter-to-smooth-noisy-data))
2. Background Subtract using `EstimatedBackground`
3. Use `PeakDetect` to find the relevant peaks

Unfortunately, the background estimation, and peak detection appear to be very sensitive to the values of $\sigma$ which is chosen. I made a simple Manipulate object to show what I mean: ([Example](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/36e6de73-3d34-474a-b5ea-ea749221fb47), Yellow=Smoothed Data, Blue=Estimated Background, Green=Background Subtracted, and Orange=Results from PeakDetect)

**EDIT**:

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[
{EstimatedBackground[smoothed[[;; , 2]], i], 
   smoothed[[;; , 2]], 
   smoothed[[;; , 2]] - EstimatedBackground[smoothed[[;; , 2]], i], 
   PeakDetect[
     smoothed[[;; , 2]] - EstimatedBackground[smoothed[[;; , 2]], i], 
     n]*smoothed[[;; , 2]]},
 DataRange -> {400, 800}, 
  PlotRange -> All
], 
{i, 0, 100}, {n, 0, 100}
]
```

I find that a good $\sigma$ value for the Background Subtraction for this particular dataset is ~30 and a good $\sigma$ for the Peak Detection is ~25.

To be clear, the left side of the plot is not of interest to me. It's an example of a standard semiconductor absorbance spectrum (like [this](https://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/semi_en/kap_5/illustr/absorption.gif)), and my peak of interest is simply superimposed on it. Ideally I would simply subtract out the left side using a known function, but it's complicated since it's the result of multiple compounds in a given sample.

In short:

1. Is there a better way to do this, which will result in more generalizable code?
2. If my approach is the best way to do this (which I doubt) how can it be improved to require minimal human intervention?

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't aware that you had to do that for cloud objects. I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you for adding the code!

Comment: @BesselF I get a 403 error when trying to access your cloud code example... (but the data link works OK)

Comment: I reposted the Manipulate link that should be accessible. Let me know if it doesn't work.