# "Spline" interpolation not working

Tags: interpolation, data, filtering

I have the following sample data

```
data={-0.16952640034568625, -0.26279580767569677, -0.34698969646746414, -0.41925051155260096, -0.4827096382888264, -0.537535673345224, -0.5788064930492074, -0.6021747066904077, -0.6227212709656731, 
  -0.645218874215294, -0.6529681030876083, -0.680922499828511, -0.6990457831526136, -0.7171409355950619, -0.7551752118001522, -0.7567042771077576, -0.7855256227381958, -0.8192822457689661, 
  -0.9070805586340569, -0.9355711982148748, -0.9702794105459295, -0.9709478394058481, -1.00960304274483, -1.0449022765424374, -1.0568778288104164, -1.089960160477901, -1.1366859307252049, 
  -1.1536965306829752, -1.1739583080589295, -1.218790605784555, -1.2454443064015006, -1.2556730491342347, -1.3020486408969945, -1.3418965449194218, -1.3492791213811992, -1.3961112371912672, 
  -1.4415701870346849, -1.444004907160478, -1.4918390718475778, -1.525102287594224, -1.5405835817417768, -1.5643157209521064, -1.5897076791692157, -1.6397299682197652, -1.656067204344228, 
  -1.690364074785328, -1.7290189420463014, -1.7645899501306705, -1.7814318696151457, -1.821141175417192, -1.862144107248702, -1.8807315364476849, -1.916046576313208, -1.9582601701356717, 
  -2.014751276413228, -2.0188465647853437, -2.069687763952646, -2.121381464658644, -2.167215147969383, -2.1697380854449326, -2.215207289423022, -2.25750295652639, -2.2900413566371123, 
  -2.2903942320960273, -2.315418523785436, -2.326637389424847, -2.3393266664011994, -2.3621807136810262, -2.383913838102939, -2.4045837785699717, -2.4309069078167242, -2.441281250644293, 
  -2.462414537853321, -2.4871407077668786, -2.510408023054892, -2.5321943008486754, -2.5360753455730203, -2.553217387754695, -2.573080036902164, -2.5882285548479715, -2.59607485927888, 
  -2.602916762267663, -2.6172366828046867, -2.63102036476022, -2.6443027245568675, -2.648009131235619, -2.6609251531154725, -2.677376846682117, -2.6933543178580965, -2.693498920957068, 
  -2.7089179311530374, -2.7238797751148525, -2.733717960345198, -2.73810045626225, -2.7523913155308444, -2.7657009087431543, -2.769454907195716, -2.7790216819563263, -2.791532841390251, 
  -2.8002610285791865, -2.8037687440535124, -2.815639884564145, -2.826851315579978, -2.826898969699483, -2.8378849463648463, -2.8459393302115785, -2.8464883749525836, -2.8539163210552405, 
  -2.8628792969511387, -2.8629224952512264, -2.8712842930488, -2.8760217217933697, -2.877225966193879, -2.882953693493401, -2.8868502791450554}
```

which I wish to interpolate *smoothly*, but using

```
int = Interpolation[data, Method -> "Spline"]
```

I get the following[image]

So these small kinks, cusps and wiggles are supposed to disappear with `Spline` but they persist.  I would like to have a completely "polished" curve (slowly changing derivative).

Comment: It's nicer to have a semicolon at the end of `data = {...}`.

Comment: `Interpolation` is producing a $C^2$ (continuous second derivative) interpolant. `Plot @@ {int''[x], Flatten@{x, int@"Domain"}, PlotRange -> All}`. You probably want to smooth the data or fit an approximant. There have been several questions about this before. Here is a recent one with links to others: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269356/best-way-to-smooth-interpolate-and-differentiate-over-a-list-of-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding. Interpolation goes always through the given data points and is used to obtain values in between. "Smoothing" or "Filtering" is used to smooth noise data.

One of the simplest filter is e.g. the mean filter: MeanFilter[data, r]. "r" determines how strongly the data is smoothed (however, there are also more sophistic filters). E.g.:

```
ListLinePlot[{MeanFilter[data, 4]}]
```

[image]

To get the derivative you need a somewhat more sophisticated filter. E.g. "LowpassFilter". If you are interessted, you can read ""tutorial/DigitalFilterDesign" in the help.  Here is an example.

```
fun = Interpolation[LowpassFilter[data, 0.1]];
Plot[fun[x], {x, 1, Length@data}]
Plot[fun'[x], {x, 1, Length@data}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It seems that with this filter there are still some isolated points where the derivative is not defined, even if the degree is increased.

Comment: Look at the addendum to my answer.